# Javascript: Object or Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I just learned about prototype in Javascript (not the framework, the native feature). I perfectly got, at least one of its use. Example:

```
Array.prototype.myMethod = function(){
   /*do something super awesome*/
}
var a = [];
a.myMethod();
```

Reading on I came upon an example in which the author adds a ***subClass*** method to the ***Object*** object, by doing this:

```
Object.subClass = function(hash){/*return an extended object that inherits Object's attributes*/}
```

The goal is to create a method that resembles a more object-oriented language syntax.
Since I expected the book author to define such method using the prototype  feature my question is:

- Why not use *prototype*?
- Isn't more risky to add methods directly to the object rather than the prototype attached to it?
- Are there situations in which I'd prefer one way over the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why not use prototype?

Because if prototype is used then the `subClass` method is only available on instances of an `Object`. For example, to call `subClass` the following would be necessary:

```
Object.prototype.subClass = function(hash) { /* return an extended object that inherits Object's attributes */ };
function MyClass() { };

var myInstance = new MyClass();
var mySubClassInstance = myInstance.subClass(); // only accessible on instances
```

This doesn't make much sense because the author wants `subClass` to return an extended instance of the object. The intent is not to create an instance of the parent "class" and then return a new sub instance from that instance. That's unnecessary.

By defining it right on `Object`, the `subClass` instance can be created without first creating an instance of `MyClass`:

```
Object.subClass = function(hash) { /* return an extended object that inherits Object's attributes */ };
function MyClass() { };

var mySubClassInstance = MyClass.subClass();
```

> Isn't more risky to add methods directly to the object rather than the prototype attached to it?
>   Are there situations in which I'd prefer one way over the other.

- Add to prototype to add members to instances of that object.
- Add to the object to add members to that object (similar to the idea of static members).

Comment: Perfectly clear explanation, and actually pretty obvious looking back. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want method to be able to access class instance (with `this` keyword), use prototype. If you don't need `this`, declare function as member of class itself, so that you can call it without object.