# JavaScript: rationale for methods on Object vs. Object.prototype in language standard

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Is there a rationale for why some of the convenience and reflection methods in JavaScript are defined on `Object`, whereas others are defined on `Object.prototype`? For instance, to find out whether an object `a` is a prototype of object `b`, you call `isPrototypeOf` **on `a`**:

```
a.isPrototypeOf(b)
```

Conversely, to get the prototype of object `a`, you call `getPrototypeOf` on `Object` with `a` as an argument:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(a)
```

To me, this seems a little counterintuitive, at least at first sight -- I would expect that the characteristics of an object (like its prototype) can be queried starting from the object itself. (In other words, I would tend to expect a `getPrototype` method on `Object.prototype`, to be called as `a.getPrototype()`, rather than a `getPrototypeOf` method on `Object`.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31276422/1826241) does a fairly good job explaining why you might want to pick one over the other, but the reasoning behind the particular decisions in the language standard (see `getPrototypeOf` example above) is not entirely clear to me. But I guess there must be one :) What is it?

Comment: Or maybe [Why were ES5 Object methods not added to Object.prototype?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9735026/1048572) would've been a better duplicate target

Comment: If `Object.getPrototypeOf()` were defined on the prototype then it would be harder to call it on objects that don't have a prototype.

Comment: @Bergi: ah, thanks a lot, that seems to be what I was looking for :) both links are useful and relevant, but I must have phrased my original question in a way that neither Google nor SO suggested these.

Comment: @Bergi and yes, seeing that there's only one possible duplicate target, your second suggestion is the better option I think

Comment: @dlukes: Well I struggle to find that post everytime I want to link it as well, I only know that I posted that answer… And the second one I just came across today in the "related questions" sidebar.